# Converting Date column to ODBC canonical format in SQL Server 2005

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

I'm dealing with the issue of converting a Date column to an ODBC canonical format in my Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

I have the following SQL query in php:

```
$sql_query = "UPDATE [$connectionInfo[Database]].[dbo].[log_record] SET [lock]='0' WHERE CONVERT [Date] = '".json_encode($value['Date']['date'])."'
```

Basically, the part `'".json_encode($value['Date']['date'])."'` works and is printed as `'"2017-06-01 00:00:00"'`. But it's the [Date] column that's the problem. How can I compare them? It generates the following error:

> error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from
>   character string. query: UPDATE [dba_sql].[dbo].[log_record] SET
>   [lock]='0' WHERE [Date] = '"2017-06-01 00:00:00"'

I attempted the following, but in vain:

```
$sql_query = "UPDATE [$connectionInfo[Database]].[dbo].[log_record] SET [lock]='0' WHERE CONVERT CONVERT(varchar, Date, 120) = '".json_encode($value['Date']['date'])."'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the double quotes, and remove the `convert` hanging in your code. There is no need to convert the `date` in your table to a character type for your comparison.

The following is valid: `select convert(date,'2017-06-01 00:00:00')`

This is not: `select convert(date,'"2017-06-01 00:00:00"')`

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/NUNAD13593

---

Also note: The only truly safe formats for date/time literals in SQL Server, at least for `datetime` and `smalldatetime`, are: `YYYYMMDD` and `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.nnn]`

Reference: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

For example, if you have a language setting that implicitly sets the `dateformat` to `dmy`, then the same input for two different conversions can yield different output, if not an error:

```
set language 'british';
select toDatatype = 'datetime' ,val = convert(char(10),convert(datetime,'2017-06-01 00:00:00'),120)
union all
select toDatatype = 'date', val = convert(char(10),convert(date,'2017-06-01 00:00:00'),120)
```

returns:

```
+------------+------------+
| toDatatype |    val     |
+------------+------------+
| datetime   | 2017-01-06 |
| date       | 2017-06-01 |
+------------+------------+
```

and `select convert(datetime,'2017-06-13')` would return an error where as `select convert(date,'2017-06-13')` would return `2017-06-13`.

Comment: I tried it out and it didn't work. Here's my attempt:      $sql_query = "UPDATE [$connectionInfo[Database]].[dbo].[form_record] SET [lock]='0' WHERE CONVERT(Date,'2017-06-01 00:00:00') = '".json_encode($value['Date']['date'])."' AND [form_name]='".$value['form_name']."' AND [I/O#]='".$value['I/O#']."' AND [facility]='".$value['facility']."'";

Comment: @Andrew That's not what I was suggesting. Your error says `WHERE [Date] = '"2017-06-01 00:00:00"'`. See those double quotes around the date there? Get rid of those.